# "transaction is active" error while migrating django model

Tags: python, django

I renamed some field in my model, and ran

```
python manage.py makemigration # successful
python manage.py migrate
```

On the second command I get

> NotSupportedError: Renaming the 'my_model'.''my_column' while in a transaction is not supported on SQLite because it would break referential integrity. Try adding `atomic = False` to the Migration class

However, I don't see which transaction it means. There is no python or sqlite process that is running at the time I get that error. Is some lock left in sqlite or django file? And how do I fix that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the app folder in which you have renamed some field in the model.
when you have ran this command

`python manage.py makemigration`.

This in the app folder inside migration folder would have made a migration file (last file, eg: 000_initial).

Open that file inside that Migration Class would be written in the beginning of that class add this.

`atomic = False`

It will look something like this

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    atomic = False
```

That will help you run command error free:

`python manage.py migrate`

For more Reference check: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/writing-migrations/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, my main question is how do I detect the running transaction. I can get away with `atomic=False` for now, but it's not safe in the long run

Comment: By this referential integrity what i can say is the column you are trying to rename is already a foreign key or some relation is created on another table so it cant be renamed and it throws you the error.

On databases that support DDL transactions (SQLite and PostgreSQL), migrations will run inside a transaction by default. For use cases such as performing data migrations on large tables

Comment: so, the "transaction" refers to the actual renaming, inside sqlite? nothing python-related??

Comment: Yes its the same db transaction. Even you can run transaction manually in Django by importing transaction class. Where atomic() function is used to start a new transaction and on completion of transaction you can use on_commit().